# Column stored as List; how can I split as COLUMNS in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

assume "Tags" column as stores as below; How can I split into multiple columns or set into one list?

desired as " To be combined as List and filter-out duplication

```
"Tags"
['Saudi', 'law', 'Saudi Arabia', 'rules']
['Hindi', 'Tamil', 'imposition', 'cbse', 'neet', 'Tamil Nadu', 'India']
['Stephen', 'Hawkins', 'Tamil', 'predictions', 'future', 'science', 'scientist', 'top 5', 'five']
['Bigg Boss', 'Tamil', 'Kamal', 'big', 'boss']
['Mary', 'real', 'story', 'Tamil', 'history']
['football', 'Tamil', 'FIFA', '2018', 'world cup', 'MG', 'top', '10', 'ten']
['India', 'Tamil', 'poor', 'rich', 'money', 'MG', 'why', 'Indians']
```

Comment: Can you provide an example output to make it clear?

Comment: Assume that, column 'Tags' stores as list as below; 
['thamizh', 'kannada', 'karnataka', 'bangalore', 'mysore', 'bengaluru', 'Bengaluru', 'malayalam', 'kerala', 'chennai', 'yash', 'kgf', 'songs', 'kannada songs',  'news', 'today']
['songs', 'kannada songs',  'news', 'today']
['mysore', 'bengaluru', 'Bengaluru', 'malayalam',] 

I would like combine in one list and then filterout duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["Tags"].explode().unique()
```

Or:

```
np.unique(df["Tags"].sum())
```

**Edit:**

Maybe you need:

```
import ast
df["Tags"].apply(ast.literal_eval).explode().unique()
```

Comment: Assume that, column 'Tags' stores as list as below; 

['thamizh', 'kannada', 'karnataka', 'bangalore', 'mysore', 'bengaluru', 'Bengaluru', 'malayalam', 'kerala', 'chennai', 'yash', 'kgf', 'songs', 'kannada songs',  'news', 'today']
['songs', 'kannada songs',  'news', 'today']
['mysore', 'bengaluru', 'Bengaluru', 'malayalam',] 

I would like to combine in one list and then filter out duplication.

Answer (score 0):

If need list without duplicates use set comprehension with `set` if performance is important:

```
L = list(set(y for x in df['Tags'] for y in x))
```

If possible there are `list`s saved like strings use:

```
import ast

L = list(set(y for x in df['Tags'].dropna() for y in ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

---

```
print (L)
['FIFA', 'Mary', 'world cup', 'rich', 'story', 'Tamil', 'rules', 'neet', 'money', 'Kamal', 'Hindi', 'big', 'cbse', 'imposition', 'football', 'MG', 'history', 'predictions', 'why', 'Tamil Nadu', 'top 5', 'ten', '10', 'Bigg Boss', 'India', 'Stephen', 'top', 'poor', 'law', 'Saudi', 'real', 'Indians', 'future', 'boss', 'five', '2018', 'scientist', 'Saudi Arabia', 'science', 'Hawkins']
```

Comment: Assume that, column 'Tags' stores as list as below; 

['thamizh', 'kannada', 'karnataka', 'bangalore', 'mysore', 'bengaluru', 'Bengaluru', 'malayalam', 'kerala', 'chennai', 'yash', 'kgf', 'songs', 'kannada songs',  'news', 'today']
['songs', 'kannada songs',  'news', 'today']
['mysore', 'bengaluru', 'Bengaluru', 'malayalam',] 

I would like to combine in one list and then filter out duplication.

Comment: @Karthikeyan -so `L = list(set([y for x in df['Tags'] for y in x]))` failed? answer was edited.

Comment: print(list(set([y for x in data['Tags'] for y in x])))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: import ast
print(list(set(y for x in data['Tags'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x))))
ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
Column itself contain Nan value instead of Lists

Comment: @Karthikeyan Can you try `L = list(set(y for x in df['Tags'].dropna() for y in ast.literal_eval(x)))`?